# How do I do an assert on values in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Say I have a simple `pyspark` dataframe

```
Orderline = Row("OrderID", "Item", "Amount", "Price")
orderline1 = Orderline("1001", "Milk", 1, 0.99)
orderline2 = Orderline("1001", "Bread", 3, 1.99)
orderline3 = Orderline("1002", "Milk", 1, 0.99)
orderline4 = Orderline("1002", "Sugar", 1, 0.59)
orderline5 = Orderline("1003", "Yoghurt", 1, 1.49)
orderline6 = Orderline("1003", "Candy", 1, 0.99)
orderline7 = Orderline("1003", "Cola", 3, 1.49)
orderline8 = Orderline("1004", "Milk", 3, 0.99)

orderlines = spark.createDataFrame([orderline1, orderline2, orderline3, orderline4, orderline5, orderline6, orderline7, orderline8])
```

I want to be able to do data quality checks on my data. These can be complicated business logic, yet some are very simple. For example, in this case I'd like to check if all prices are positive.

I have tried several things, such as

```
assert orderlines['Price'] > 0.0 # or
assert orderlines['Price'].collect() > 0.0
```

or

```
assert orderlines.select('Price') > 0.0
assert orderlines.select('Price').collect() > 0.0
```

What is the most pyspark-onic way to do such checks?

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ

Comment: For now, I use `assert orderlines.filter(orderlines['Price'] <= 0.0).count() == 0`, although this still doesn't feel as the best way to do this